# How to append a WebControl immediately after a WebControl in CodeBehind

Tags: c#

Now that i've been MVCing for quite sometime i decide to pop some classic C# .Net into my 8 track and have gotten the following issue:

I have a TextBox WebControl on my aspx page that in the code behind i want to simply append a LiteralControl after it.

This doesn't work:

```
TextBoxAge.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Invalid Age."));
```

This works but all the way at the bottom:

```
TextBoxAge.Controls.Parent.Add(new LiteralControl("Invalid Age."));
```

Can you help me!?

For example the HTML will show:

```
<div>
<input name="TextBoxAge" type="text" id="TextBoxAge" class="Age">
Invalid Age.
</div>
```

This should be purely dynamic and relative to the control at hand.

**Solution:**

```
TextBoxAge.Parent.Controls.AddAt(TextBoxAge.Parent.Controls.IndexOf(T‌​extBoxAge),new LiteralControl("<span>Invalid Age.</span>"));
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: So you want to append a literal control, but you want it to appear at a specific location on the web page?  Why don't you show us a little more of your code.

Comment: wow! this is clean, elegant and readable code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this. (Don't remember if AddAt will replace the control at the specified index )

```
var textBoxAgeIndex = TextBoxAge.Parent.Controls.IndexOf(TextBoxAge);

TextBoxAge.Parent.Controls.AddAt(textBoxAgeIndex +1, new LiteralControl("Invalid Age."));
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Sorry +1 instead it helps, but it is too sloppy and breaks the rest of my page.

Comment: AddAt does not replace, it inserts

Comment: @Pinch : yes the positioning will depend on your markup structure. You might want to use a Label or a Panel instead of a Literal, that would help you apply some styling. BTW seems a perfect case for using Validators

Comment: TextBoxAge.Parent.Controls.AddAt(TextBoxAge.Parent.Controls.IndexOf(TextBoxAge),new LiteralControl("<span>BINGO</span>"));

Comment: Solution was strongly based on your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use an a [PlaceHolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> From MSDN: Use the PlaceHolder control as a container to store server
>   controls that are dynamically added to the Web page.

```
PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Invalid Age."));
```

Comment: @Pinch you should get the parent,iterate the controls hierarchy until you find the "TextBoxAge" and then insert the literal after it. It is cleaner and easier to use a placeholder.

Comment: really curious about the downvote. please could you explain?